# What is the best way to define a static property which is defined once per sub-class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, static

I wrote the following console app to test static properties:

```
using System;

namespace StaticPropertyTest
{
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public static int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedAlpha : BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class DerivedBeta : BaseClass
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DerivedBeta.MyProperty = 7;
            Console.WriteLine(DerivedAlpha.MyProperty); // outputs 7
        }
    }
}
```

As this console app demonstrates, the `MyProperty` property exists once for all instances of BaseClass.  Is there a pattern to use which would allow me to define a static property which will have allocated storage for each sub-class type?

Given the above example, I would like all instances of `DerivedAlpha` to share the same static property, and all instances of `DerivedBeta` to share *another* instance of the static property.

**Why am I trying to do this?**

I am lazily initializing a collection of class property names with certain attributes (via reflection).  The property names will be identical for each derived class instance, so it seems wasteful to store this in each class instance.  I can't make it static in the base class, because different sub-classes will have different properties.

I don't want to replicate the code which populates the collection (via reflection) in each derived class.  I know that one possible solution is to define the method to populate the collection in the base class, and call it from each derived class, but this is not the most elegant solution.

**Update - Example of what I'm doing**

At Jon's request, here's an example of what I'm trying to do.  Basically, I can optionally decorate properties in my classes with the `[SalesRelationship(SalesRelationshipRule.DoNotInclude)]` attribute (there are other attributes, this is just a simplified example).

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    // I want this property to be static but exist once per derived class.
    public List<string> PropertiesWithDoNotInclude { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        // Code here will populate PropertiesWithDoNotInclude with
        // all properties in class marked with
        // SalesRelationshipRule.DoNotInclude.
        //
        // I want this code to populate this property to run once per
        // derived class type, and be stored statically but per class type.
    }
}

public class FooEntity : BaseEntity
{
   [SalesRelationship(SalesRelationshipRule.DoNotInclude)]
   public int? Property_A { get; set; }

   public int? Property_B { get; set; }

   [SalesRelationship(SalesRelationshipRule.DoNotInclude)]
   public int? Property_C { get; set; }
}

public class BarEntity : BaseEntity
{
   public int? Property_D { get; set; }

   [SalesRelationship(SalesRelationshipRule.DoNotInclude)]
   public int? Property_E { get; set; }

   public int? Property_F { get; set; }
}
```

**Desired end result**

Accessing `FooEntity.PropertiesWithDoNotInclude` returns a `List<string>` of:

```
{
  "Property_A",
  "Property_C"
}
```

Accessing `BarEntity.PropertiesWithDoNotInclude` returns a `List<string>` of:

```
{
  "Property_E"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jon has a good solution as usual, although I don't see what good attributes do here, since they have to be explicitly added to every subtype and they don't act like properties.

The `Dictionary` approach can definitely work.  Here's another way to do that, which explicitly declares that there will be one variable per subclass of `BaseEntity`:

```
class FilteredProperties<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
     static public List<string> Values { get; private set; }
     // or static public readonly List<string> Values = new List<string>();
     static FilteredProperties()
     {
         // logic to populate the list goes here
     }
}
```

The drawback of this is that it's rather difficult to pair with a `GetType()` call such as you might use in methods of `BaseEntity`.  A `Dictionary`, or wrapper thereto which implements lazy population, is better for that usage.

Comment: The OP specified that "The property names will be identical for each derived class instance" - which suggests it's effectively a constant for each class, which means it can be an attribute which is then fetched by reflection. No, it doesn't behave exactly like a property - but it lets you specify a value per class and then fetch that value... Now we've got more information in the question, it's clearer what the OP is trying to do, and a dictionary from `Type` to *something* is probably the way to go.

Comment: Is your solution meant to use a singleton (per type argument) approach? If so, I like it - but you could do with expanding it a bit.

Comment: @Jon: oops I missed a `static` keyword.

Comment: Right - this makes a lot of sense now. Will modify my answer to refer to this as a good solution. It may well be worth explicitly stating that the way generics work in C#, you end up with a separate type per set of type arguments, which is why it works.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible approaches:

- Use attributes; decorate each subclass with an attribute, e.g.

  ```
  [MyProperty(5)]
  public class DerivedAlpha
  {
  }

  [MyProperty(10)]
  public class DerivedBeta
  {
  }
  ```

  That only works when they're effectively constants, of course.
- Use a dictionary:

  ```
  var properties = new Dictionary<Type, int>
  {
      { typeof(DerivedAlpha), 5) },
      { typeof(DerivedBeta), 10) },
  };
  ```

EDIT: Now that we have more context, Ben's answer is a really good one, using the way that generics work in C#. It's like the dictionary example, but with laziness, thread-safety and simple global access all built in.

Comment: I have expanded my answer.

Comment: In your second example, did you mean `DerivedBeta` for the second item? :)