# Static generic using Type

Tags: c#, generics, static

I have a tree of classes. To properly load them I need to know all ancestral classes of specific instance. I.e. when loading some specific instance (this) I need also to trigger loading all it's ancestor types.

Currently I've done this via function in one of top ancestors, which gets initial type using this.GetType() and collects Type.BaseType into an array. Also I've done the same thing using extension method to Type class. Both solutions work nicely, but I'm a bit worried that I rebuild this array all the time (lots of small subclasses with specialized functions with several ancestors each).

So I've been looking for alternate aproach. Right now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public static class AncestralTypes<T>
{
    private static Type[] _All;
    public static Type[] All { get { return _All ?? (_All =GetAllTypes());}} 
    private static Type[] GetAllTypes()
    {
        List<Type> all_types = new List<Type>();
        var a = typeof(T);
        all_types.Add(a);
        var to = typeof(object);
        if (a != to)
            while ((a = a.BaseType) != to)      // Iterate until we reach Object type ancestor
                all_types.Add(a);
        return all_types.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As long as I test this approach with statements like

```
AncestralTypes<MyCustomClass39>.All
```

it works perfectly well. It triggers generation only once per type (then it's stored). Everything looks good.

**PROBLEM:** I cannot get it to work inside loading function (defined in one of ancestors) using "this" keyword. It won't accept this.GetType(). Is there a way to send in type of "this" object into such a generic? I expected something like:

```
foreach(var t in AncestralTypes<this.GetType()>.All) DoJob(t);
```

to work. Maybe I'm missing something really minor?

Example:

- I have class BaseClass, which defines function Load, which actually uses those all types to properly initialize and store derivative
- I have class DerivedClass1, which inherits from BaseClass
- I have class DerivedClass2, which inherits also from BaseClass
- I create instance of some of DerivedClass# and call inherited Load function, which should use "this" keyword type and all ancestral types to initialize everything correctly. 
  So I cannot just use specific subclass.

Comment: Generics are compile-time only, so you can't use a method call to assign them.

Comment: What about an Extension Method on Type class? Then you could call something like this.GetType().GetAncestralTypes().

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: As I wrote above - I already did both Extension and a function inside base class. Both work, but both recreate lists on each call, rather then once per class.

Comment: @Magus: I'm not sure what you meant tbh. I can create instance of generic List for example via typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {this.GetType()}).GetConstructor... It could be possible in my case as well.

Comment: Well, with reflection, you can also access private variables. What's your point? Most things don't apply when reflection comes into play.

Comment: @Magus: if you are absolutely positive, that it's a no-go - it's ok. Other solutions work. It's more like an experiment to make it a bit neater + to improve knowledge of other sides of C#. Also I'm looking into a way to store static things once per subclass.

Comment: It might be possible to use what you mentioned before and instead of getting the constructor, get the first method named "All". I'd really try not to use such code often, however. It's rather awful to look at.

Comment: If you want to store the list once per subtype, you could make a custom static class with something like a static `Dictionary<string (TypeName), Type[]>`. You could use it on the extension method.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: Could you post your suggestion as separate answer, so I could mark it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to maintain a static Dictionary what would hold the Ancestral Type List per subclass. It would be used to cache the types and therefore avoid building the lists repeatedly, which would mean some performance gain.

Something like this:

```
static Dictionary<string (TypeName), Type[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mt.Schneiders and Magus I did a test of 5 aproaches with 500k tests (ran several times, timers were pretty close all times):

1. Function in one of ancestors (dynamic) - 302ms
2. Extension method to Type (dynamic) - 314ms
3. Static generic for known type (static) - 25ms
4. Static generic for unknown type (via reflection) - 1069ms
5. ## 1 but with added static Dictionary - 41ms

I've decided to keep #5 (function with static dictionary) approach. Mt.Schneiders, if you post your dictionary suggestion as a separate answer - I'll be glad to mark it as a solution. Thanks to both of you though.

P.S.: Decided not to use extension method as it's just a bit slower according to tests + it looks worse: customclassinstance.GetType().GetAllTypes()  -vs-  customclassinstance.AllTypes

**EDIT**: Looking at answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780469/what-is-the-best-way-to-define-a-static-property-which-is-defined-once-per-sub-c) I've also decided to try approach with base class being defined as Base< T>. Custom class would look like "CustomClass: Base< CustomClass>" then, yet this allows to use almost the same thing as I've wanted initially.
Did additional test:

- with Base< T> and static Type[] property - around 30ms.